# Thread blocked on DoNDirectCall__PatchGetThreadCall during managed to unmanaged call

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading

I have a C# program, which is calling to a managed C++ wrapper, which is in turn calling through to unmanaged C++ code. When I am executing this code I can see periods where the thread is waiting for synchronisation on the method `DoNDirectCall__PatchGetThreadCall`. The stack trace looks somewhat like

```
- Csharp.Code.MyClass in MyC#.dll
  -> Managed.C++.Interface in MyManagedC++.dll
  -> Managed.C++.Internal in MyManagedC++.dll
  -> DoNDirectCall__PatchGetThreadCall in clr.dll
```

So the unmanaged code I am calling through to does not show up at all in the thread stack. Does anyone know if the `DoNDirectCall__PatchGetThreadCall` will actually represent the time spent in my unmanaged function, or is it actually doing something else that is causing threads to wait on synchronization?